# file_put_contents half a file

Tags: php, ftp

im using file_put_contents over FTP and it only seems to be saving half the file. I'm posting an SVG over via ajax (which the server is receiving in full) and then saving to an external server. The process only takes a few seconds so it can't be a process time issue. Has anyone else had this? regards

```
$options = array( 'ftp' => array( 'overwrite' => true ) );
$svgSavePath = "ftp://{$user}:{$password}@{$host}/svgs/{$id}.svg";
$stream = stream_context_create( $options );
file_put_contents( $svgSavePath, $svg, 0, $stream );
```

Comment: Show relevant code. If `file_put_contents()` were broken, you wouldn't be the first to encounter it.

Comment: The code is fine, I changed it to save to the same server and it saves in full, point it to another and saves only half the file.

Comment: The two subscriptions are on the same account so instead of doing it over FTP, I've used the path and is saving fine, must be an option in the stream context?